# Issue with background image and responsiveness

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, magnific-popup

I'm using Magnific Popup to display two halves of content side by side; the left side is a div with a background image that can be of two different sizes, but the problem is that I'm struggling to style the images with responsive dimensions to fill their containers.

At the moment, I've had to set manual widths and heights for each, which I'm trying to avoid. I've opted for a background image instead of an img element so I can display different images on mobile.

I've tried various `background-size`, `position`, and `height` values to no avail. I think if I understand the issue, I'd have better luck solving it. I'm assuming that the problem is with one of the image `div`'s containers.

HTML:

```
<div class="left-half">
<div class="popup-screenshot" id="mts-screenshot"></div>
</div>
<div class="right-half">
<h3>Description</h3>
<p>Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.</p>
<p>
<h3>Details</h3>
<ul>
<li><span>Date:</span> December 2011 - Present</li>
<li><span>Category:</span> Design/development</li>
<li><span>Technologies:</span> XHTML/CSS3, JavaScript/jQuery</li>
</ul>
</p>
<p><a href="http://www.mtscollective.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Launch Website</a></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-half, .white-popup .right-half {
  margin: 20px;
}
.left-half {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.right-half {
  width: 40%;
}
.popup-screenshot {
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#mts-screenshot {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/upKnQUT.png");
}
div#mtsm-popup {
  max-width: 800px;
}
div#mtsm-popup .left-half {
  width: 30%;
}
div#mtsm-popup .right-half {
  width: 55%;
}
div#mtsm-screenshot.popup-screenshot {
  width: 266px;
  height: 542px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#mtsm-screenshot {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/NghCrTD.jpg");
}
#api-screenshot {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/Wysc9he.png");
}
.right-half {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3gLyhad3/1/

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Pixels are from the 90's and if your target is repsonsiveness, use vw(=viewport width), vh(=viewport height) and %. All these units are made for responsive sites and will automatically rescale if you rescale your browser. Beware: 100vw = 100%.
Then: Add 'center top" after your url-css-function to avoid the div to take wrong parts of the image as background.
Next: Setting the width and height both usually doesn't make sense, decide on setring either width or height to a defined value and set the other one to 'auto'.

> Pro Tip:
>   You can make '@media'-rules that only apply if a certain requirement is given. For example:
>       @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
>           .left-half {
>               width: 80%;
>           }
>       }

This will make the '.left-half' 80% width when the screen is smaller than 768px and if it is a screen.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I already knew all of this. I'm not using pixels because I want to or think I should, but because it's the only method that's worked so far while I try to figure out a responsive solution. My issue is that using percentage isn't giving me the desired result. I'm already using a media query for mobile, but I'm trying to avoid having to manually set the width at different breakpoints. I was hoping for an example that I could understand better. I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I can help you further when I'm at home.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I've tried so far with no progress: http://jsfiddle.net/3gLyhad3/2/.

Comment: Are you aware that your image is quite small and not really suited as a background?

Comment: It's 800x600px, but it's not a page background--it's the background for half of a lightbox popup.

Comment: The actual section they fill is about 500px wide, and I'm using different images for mobile. This isn't an issue.